# What does it mean when a variable "has been demoted" in the PTX?

Tags: cuda, nvcc, ptx

In the function body of my CUDA kernel, I have a few `__shared__` array variables, of a fixed size. When I look at the compiled PTX code (SM 7.5) for one of these arrays, I see a comment saying:

```
// my_kernel(t1 p1, t2 p2)::my_variable has been demoted
```

... and this line appears among `.global` lines in the PTX, right before the compiled kernel itself. Then, within the kernel, I get:

```
// demoted variable
.shared .align 4 .b8 my_kernel(t1 p1, t2 p2)::my_variable [1234];
```

My questions:

1. In what way is such a variable "demoted"? Isn't it defined just like I asked it to be?
2. Under what circumstances are such variables "demoted"?

Notes:

- I'm using CUDA 11.2.
- I've quoted demangled lines from my PTX. The actual names are  `_ZZ8blahblah...`.
- The array variables with which I see this "demoting" are either two-dimensional fixed-size arrays, or have an element type which is a struct (e.g. `struct { unsigned short data[2]; }`); perhaps that's related somehow.

Comment: @talonmies: 1. I was assuming this has a standard meaning; but per your suggestion I'll go generate an MRE. 2. What do you mean by the "global->shared->global" cycle? I started out with a shared variableaft all.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: These variables likely can't be optimized into registers (they're too big and access indices are not known at compile time); but let me see about that MRE.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/what-causes-ptx-compiler-to-demote-shared-variable/79982) this appears to be based on whether or not the shared variable scope can be restricted to a single function (i.e. a single kernel).    Even very complex kernel functions with shared usage that I have looked at demote the shared variables.

Here's a simple example where it is demoted and not demoted.

Not demoted:

```
$ vi t1.cu
$ cat t1.cu
__shared__ float s[32];
__global__ void k(float *  my_ptr){
  s[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
  *my_ptr = s[threadIdx.x];
}
__global__ void k1(float *  my_ptr){
  s[threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
  *my_ptr = s[threadIdx.x];
}
$ nvcc -ptx t1.cu
$ cat t1.ptx
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
//
// Compiler Build ID: CL-29373293
// Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
// Based on NVVM 7.0.1
//

.version 7.2
.target sm_52
.address_size 64

        // .globl       _Z1kPf
.shared .align 4 .b8 s[128];

.visible .entry _Z1kPf(
        .param .u64 _Z1kPf_param_0
)
{
        .reg .f32       %f<2>;
        .reg .b32       %r<5>;
        .reg .b64       %rd<3>;


        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z1kPf_param_0];
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
        mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
        cvt.rn.f32.u32  %f1, %r1;
        shl.b32         %r2, %r1, 2;
        mov.u32         %r3, s;
        add.s32         %r4, %r3, %r2;
        st.shared.f32   [%r4], %f1;
        st.global.f32   [%rd2], %f1;
        ret;

}
        // .globl       _Z2k1Pf
.visible .entry _Z2k1Pf(
        .param .u64 _Z2k1Pf_param_0
)
{
        .reg .b32       %r<6>;
        .reg .b64       %rd<3>;


        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z2k1Pf_param_0];
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
        mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
        shl.b32         %r2, %r1, 2;
        mov.u32         %r3, s;
        add.s32         %r4, %r3, %r2;
        mov.u32         %r5, 0;
        st.shared.u32   [%r4], %r5;
        st.global.u32   [%rd2], %r5;
        ret;

}
```

Demoted:

```
$ cat t1.cu
__global__ void k(float *  my_ptr){
  __shared__ float s[32];
  s[threadIdx.x] = threadIdx.x;
  *my_ptr = s[threadIdx.x];
}
__global__ void k1(float *  my_ptr){
  __shared__ float s[32];
  s[threadIdx.x] = 0.0f;
  *my_ptr = s[threadIdx.x];
}
$ nvcc -ptx t1.cu
$ cat t1.ptx
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
//
// Compiler Build ID: CL-29373293
// Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
// Based on NVVM 7.0.1
//

.version 7.2
.target sm_52
.address_size 64

        // .globl       _Z1kPf
// _ZZ1kPfE1s has been demoted
// _ZZ2k1PfE1s has been demoted

.visible .entry _Z1kPf(
        .param .u64 _Z1kPf_param_0
)
{
        .reg .f32       %f<2>;
        .reg .b32       %r<5>;
        .reg .b64       %rd<3>;
        // demoted variable
        .shared .align 4 .b8 _ZZ1kPfE1s[128];

        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z1kPf_param_0];
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
        mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
        cvt.rn.f32.u32  %f1, %r1;
        shl.b32         %r2, %r1, 2;
        mov.u32         %r3, _ZZ1kPfE1s;
        add.s32         %r4, %r3, %r2;
        st.shared.f32   [%r4], %f1;
        st.global.f32   [%rd2], %f1;
        ret;

}
        // .globl       _Z2k1Pf
.visible .entry _Z2k1Pf(
        .param .u64 _Z2k1Pf_param_0
)
{
        .reg .b32       %r<6>;
        .reg .b64       %rd<3>;
        // demoted variable
        .shared .align 4 .b8 _ZZ2k1PfE1s[128];

        ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z2k1Pf_param_0];
        cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
        mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
        shl.b32         %r2, %r1, 2;
        mov.u32         %r3, _ZZ2k1PfE1s;
        add.s32         %r4, %r3, %r2;
        mov.u32         %r5, 0;
        st.shared.u32   [%r4], %r5;
        st.global.u32   [%rd2], %r5;
        ret;

}
```

As an aside, there do appear to be cases where the PTX generator can delete the shared variable entirely, but this is not directly related to the question here.

Comment: Well, in my case, these are variables which are apriori restricted to a single function - as they are defined in the body of the kernel function. So my case is essentially the second k1. But then... what is the "demotion" happening there? a function-scope shared variable appears in PTX and in the CUDA function.

Comment: The demotion is a conversion of the scope of the variable from implicit global scope to local scope for that function.  The variable is obviously already locally scoped in that case but there may be a promotion activity that occurs in frontend processing as well.  You might wish to read the entire thread I linked.